# How does `for` work in this recursive Clojure code?

Tags: for-loop, recursion, clojure, list-comprehension

Clojure beginner here. Here's some code I'm trying to understand, from http://iloveponies.github.io/120-hour-epic-sax-marathon/sudoku.html (one page of a rather nice beginning Clojure course):

---

```
Subset sum is a classic problem. Here’s how it goes. You are given:

    a set of numbers, like #{1 2 10 5 7}
    and a number, say 23

and you want to know if there is some subset of the original set that sums up to the target. 
We’re going to solve this by brute force using a backtracking search.

Here’s one way to implement it:

(defn sum [a-seq]
  (reduce + a-seq))

(defn subset-sum-helper [a-set current-set target]
  (if (= (sum current-set) target)
    [current-set]
    (let [remaining (clojure.set/difference a-set current-set)]
      (for [elem remaining
            solution (subset-sum-helper a-set
                                        (conj current-set elem)
                                        target)]
        solution))))

(defn subset-sum [a-set target]
  (subset-sum-helper a-set #{} target))

So the main thing happens inside subset-sum-helper. First of all, always check if we have found 
a valid solution. Here it’s checked with

  (if (= (sum current-set) target)
    [current-set]

If we have found a valid solution, return it in a vector (We’ll see soon why in a vector). Okay, 
so if we’re not done yet, what are our options? Well, we need to try adding some element of 
a-set into current-set and try again. What are the possible elements for this? They are those 
that are not yet in current-set. Those are bound to the name remaining here:

    (let [remaining (clojure.set/difference a-set current-set)]

What’s left is to actually try calling subset-sum-helper with each new set obtainable 
in this way:

      (for [elem remaining
            solution (subset-sum-helper a-set
                                        (conj current-set elem)
                                        target)]
        solution))))

Here first elem gets bound to the elements of remaining one at a time. For each elem, 
solution gets bound to each element of the recursive call

            solution (subset-sum-helper a-set
                                        (conj current-set elem)
                                        target)]

And this is the reason we returned a vector in the base case, so that we can use for 
in this way.
```

---

And sure enough, `(subset-sum #{1 2 3 4} 4)` returns `(#{1 3} #{1 3} #{4})`.

But why must line 3 of `subset-sum-helper` return `[current-set]`? Wouldn't that return a final answer of `([#{1 3}] [#{1 3}] [#{4}])`?

I try removing the enclosing brackets in line 3, making the function begin like this:

```
(defn subset-sum-helper [a-set current-set target]
  (if (= (sum current-set) target)
    current-set
    (let ...
```

Now `(subset-sum #{1 2 3 4} 4)` returns `(1 3 1 3 4)`, which makes it look like `let` accumulates not the three sets #{1 3}, #{1 3}, and #{4}, but rather just the "bare" numbers, giving `(1 3 1 3 4)`.

So `subset-sum-helper` is using the list comprehension `for` within a recursive calculation, and I don't understand what's happening. When I try visualizing this recursive calculation, I found myself asking, "So what happens when

```
(subset-sum-helper a-set
   (conj current-set elem)
   target)
```

doesn't return an answer because no answer is possible given its starting point?" (My best guess is that it returns `[]` or something similar.) I don't understand what the tutorial writer meant when he wrote, "And this is the reason we returned a vector in the base case, so that we can use `for` in this way."

I would greatly appreciate any help you could give me. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `subset-sum-helper` function always returns a *sequence* of solutions. When the `target` is not met, the `solution` body at the end of the `for` expression enumerates such a sequence. When `target` is met, there is only one solution to return: the `current-set` argument. It must be returned as a sequence of one element. There are many ways to do this:

```
[current-set] ; as given - simplest
(list current-set)
(cons current-set ())
(conj () current-set)
...
```

If you cause an immediate return from `subset-sum-helper` (no recursion), you'll see the *vector*:

```
=> (subset-sum #{} 0)
[#{}]
```

Otherwise you'll see a *sequence* generated by `for`, which prints like a list:

```
=> (subset-sum (set (range 1 10)) 7)
(#{1 2 4}
 #{1 2 4}
 #{1 6}
 #{1 2 4}
 #{1 2 4}
 #{2 5}
 #{3 4}
 #{1 2 4}
 #{1 2 4}
 #{3 4}
 #{2 5}
 #{1 6}
 #{7})
```

When no answer is possible, `subset-sum-helper` returns an empty sequence:

```
=> (subset-sum-helper #{2 4 6} #{} 19)
()
```

Once again, this is printed as though it were a list.

The algorithm has problems:

- It finds each solution many times - factorial of `(count s)` times for a solution `s`.
- If an adopted element `elem` overshoots the target, it
  uselessly tries adding every permutation of the `remaining` set.

---

The code is easier to understand if we recast it somewhat.

The recursive call of `subset-sum-helper` passes the first and third arguments intact. If we use `letfn` to make this function local to `subset-sum`, we can do without these arguments: they are picked up from the context. It now looks like this:

```
(defn subset-sum [a-set target]
  (letfn [(subset-sum-helper [current-set]
             (if (= (reduce + current-set) target)
                 [current-set]
                 (let [remaining (clojure.set/difference a-set current-set)]
                         (for [elem remaining
                               solution (subset-sum-helper (conj current-set elem))]
                             solution))))]
      (subset-sum-helper #{})))
```

... where the single call to the `sum` function has been expanded inline.

It is now fairly clear that `subset-sum-helper` is returning the solutions that include its single `current-set` argument. The `for` expression is enumerating, for each element `elem` of `a-set` *not* in the `current-set`, the solutions containing the current set and the element. And it is doing this in succession for all such elements. So, starting with the empty set, which all solutions contain, it generates all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this explanation helps you:

Firstly we can experiment in a minimal code the expected behaviour (with and without brackets) of the [for](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for) function but removing the recursion related code

**With brackets:**

```
(for [x #{1 2 3}
      y [#{x}]]
  y)
=> (#{1} #{2} #{3})
```

**Without brackets:**

```
(for [x #{1 2 3}
      y #{x}]
  y)
=> (1 2 3)
```

**With brackets and more elements into the brackets***:**

```
(for [x #{1 2 3}
      y [#{x}  :a :b :c]]
  y)
=> (#{1} :a :b :c #{2} :a :b :c #{3} :a :b :c)
```

So you need (on this case) the brackets to avoid iterating over the set.

If we dont use the brackets we'll have "x" as binding value for y, and if we use the brackets we'll have #{x} as binding value for y.

In other words the code author needs a set and not iterating over a set as a binding value inside its for. So she put a set into a sequence "[#{x}]"

**And summarising**
"for" function takes a vector of one or more binding-form/**collection-expr** pairs 
So if your "collection-expre" is #{:a} the iteration result will be (:a) but if your "collection-expre" is [#{:a}] the iteration result will be (#{:a})

Sorry for the redundance on my explanations but it's difficult to be clear with these nuances

Comment: This explanation helped me see an error in my thinking. I was confusing the *binding* behavior in `(let [foo #{x y z}] ... )` with the *iterating* behavior in `(for [foo #{x y z}] ... )`. Same syntax in both, but very different behaviors!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a cleaner solution, still using `for`:

```
(defn subset-sum [s target]
  (cond
    (neg? target) ()
    (zero? target) (list #{})
    (empty? s) ()
    :else (let [f (first s), ns (next s)]
            (lazy-cat
              (for [xs (subset-sum ns (- target f))] (conj xs f))
              (subset-sum ns target)))))
```